# How do they make stuff like this in LaTeX? Seems extremely hard

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

I was reading a political article and this figure was in the article. Since I use LaTeX all I could think of was how it was made.[image]

Comment: Also, the text was probably formatted using \shapepar (shapepar package), possibly using fake paragraph breaks (`\newline\vskip\parskip\indent`).  Since images are rectangular, it would have to be overlayed over the text (white space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**€dit:** completely new.

I choosed some kind of random coordinates, they could be explicit coordinates in the foreachloop as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily, 
mymark/.style={mark=square*, mark options={draw=red, fill=red!66!black, mark size=5pt}}
]

\def\List{1/Donald Duck/{2,3,4}, 
2/Bart Simpson/{2,3,4,5}, 
3/He-Man/{12,3,14}, 
4/Liam/{2,3,5,7,8,9,10,12,17}, 
5/Emma/{2,6,4}, 
6/Noah/{2,3,7,17}, 
7/Olivia/{2,3,8,1},
8/William/{2,9,10}, 
9/Ava/{2,3,11}, 
10/James/{12,3,4}, 
11/Isabella/{2,13,11}, 
12/Oliver/{2,3,5}, 
13/Sophia/{2,3,7}, 
14/Benjamin/{2,13,19}, 
15/Charlotte/{2,3,5},
16/Elijah/{2,3,16,17,1,2,5}, 
17/Mia/{2,3,17}, 
18/Lucas/{2,3,11}, 
19/Amelia/{12,13,12,17}}

\foreach \No/\Name/\Connection in \List{%%
\pgfmathsetmacro\x{\No+random(0,800)/100}
\pgfmathsetmacro\y{-1.5*mod(\No,7)}
\coordinate[] (N-\No) at (\x,\y);
\path[] plot[mymark] coordinates {(N-\No)} node[below=5pt]{\Name};
}%%

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\foreach  \No/\Name/\Connection in \List{%%
\foreach  \End in \Connection \draw[red] (N-\No) -- (N-\End);
}%%
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The points are not all connected. Some might not be connected to other points.

Comment: @Boltzee So, I think here you are... :()